# Execute native js promise in series

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have to call a promise for some async task for each item in an array but I would like to execute these serially.

Promise.all is useful only to have a new promise that merges a list of promise but it does not invoke them in a sequence.

How can I achieve this using standard promise api without third-party libraries like Q, bluebird....

Comment: Why does Promise.all not satisfy the task?

Comment: @tarini Have a look at [this article](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html). Especially at "Advanced mistake #3: promises vs promise factories" section.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You chain promises using `.then()` with a callback that returns another promise.  So, let's say you have three functions a, b and c that all return a promise.  You can chain them (execute in sequence) like this:

```
a().then(b).then(c).then(function(result) {
   // all are done here
});
```

If you are processing an array and you have a promise-returning function `myFunc` that you want to call for each item in the array, you can use a standard design pattern for arrays and promises with `.reduce()` to walk through the array one item at a time like this:

```
var items = [...];

items.reduce(function(p, item) {
    return p.then(function() {
        return myFunc(item);
    });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

As it turns out this is really just chaining a bunch of `.then()` handlers like in the first example, but using the structure of `.reduce()` to walk the array for you.

---

Starting with ES2017, you can also use async/await to serially process an array like this:

```
async function processArray(arr) {
    for (let item of arr) {
        let result = await somePromiseReturningFunc(item);
        // do something with result here before
        // going on to next array item
    }
    return someFinalResult;
}

processArray(someArray).then(result => {
    // done processing array here
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error here
});
```

Comment: Added an example of sequencing promises by walking an array with `.reduce()`.

Comment: Added an example of serially processing an array with `async/await`.