# ES6 promise execution order

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I would expect the output for the following snippet to be `1, 2, 3, 4`.  But, the actual output order is `1, 4, 3, 2`.

```
self.promiseChain = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 4000);
}).then(function () {
  console.log(1);
});

self.promiseChain.then(function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
  }).then(function () {
    console.log(2);
  });
});

self.promiseChain.then(function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
  }).then(function () {
    console.log(3);
  });
});
self.promiseChain.then(function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 200);
  }).then(function () {
    console.log(4);
  });
});
```

http://www.es6fiddle.net/imu5bhoj/

Everything I've read about promises indicates it should be possible to get the desired order in a 'flat' chain like this.  Apparently I'm missing some detail?  Could someone help point me in the right direction?

Here's a fiddle (http://www.es6fiddle.net/imu6vh1o/) for how to do it in a non-flat way, but it's harder to reason about and makes sequential chaining awkward.

I've searched similar issues on stack overflow but none of them answer the question generically using a straightforward example (that I could find).

Comment: Did you mean `self.promiseChain = self.promiseChain.then...`?

Comment: Yup @elclanrs, looks like that was my problem!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just attached three `.then()` handlers to the exact same `self.promiseChain` promise.  This is **branching**, not **chaining**.  With promises, those are very different behaviors.  Those are three handlers that will all be called one immediately after the other (without waiting for results) when `self.promiseChain` is resolved.  So, the resulting three async operations will run in parallel and finish whenever they finish, thus the results you see.

If you wanted these four operations to be sequenced, then you have to actually chain them one to another, not all chained onto the same promise.  Remember `.then()` returns a new promise and it is that returned promise that you want to chain to in order to sequence things.

You are doing this:

```
var p = somePromise();

p.then(fn1);
p.then(fn2);
p.then(fn3);
```

This will trigger `fn1`, `fn2` and `fn3` at basically the same time and `fn2` will not wait for the `fn1` promise to resolve.

If you want to sequence the operations, then you want this type of logic:

```
var p = somePromise();

p.then(fn1).then(fn2).then(fn3);
```

This will not execute `fn2` until the `fn1` promise is done and will not execute `fn3` until the `fn2` promise is done - thus sequencing the async operations.

Here's how it would be if they were actually sequenced one after another.  You can actually run this snippet (but have patience because it takes 10 seconds to run):

```js
var self = {};

self.promiseChain = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 4000);
}).then(function () {
  log(1);
});

var p = self.promiseChain.then(function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
  }).then(function () {
    log(2);
  });
});

p = p.then(function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
  }).then(function () {
    log(3);
  });
});
p = p.then(function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 200);
  }).then(function () {
    log(4);
  });
});

p.then(function() {
   // last promise is done now
   log("all done");
});

function log(x) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = x;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

See these other similar answers:

[Execute native js promise in series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445543/execute-native-js-promise-in-series/30445733#30445733)

[Understanding javascript promises; stacks and chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853578/understanding-javascript-promises-stacks-and-chaining/29854205#29854205)

[Is there a difference between promise.then.then vs promise.then; promise.then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32216619/is-there-a-difference-between-promise-then-then-vs-promise-then-promise-then/32216660#32216660)

Comment: Thank you,@jfriend00!  I guess I can understand the downvotes.  Guess I should brush up on my stackoverflow searching skills.  Anyway, my misunderstanding is crystal clear now and I can finally lift my head from my keyboard!